# Alignment by expression is not working after using "wordwrap" instead of "wrap on character"

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm using **wordwrap** in the expression dialog to wrap the field "name" after the 12th character (first line) and the 20th character (second line):

```
 wordwrap( wordwrap("name"),12),20)
```

So far so good. I could also use the "warp on character"-function in the Format-Dialog in the Layer-Properties. But the first way is the best solution in my case.

But there is one problem: if I use the wordwrap, I'm not able to use the "Alignment" by expression!

[image]

For me, it seems like a bug? Is there a other way to align my labels?

Comment: I can confirm this issue. Please report it on http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: But calling wordwrap inside wordwrap does not lead to the results you seem to want to achieve because wordwrap affects the whole string anyway and not just the next linebreak.

Comment: @MAP currently the multiline alignment only works when you use the wrap on character option. I have a fix to get it working using the `wrapword` function as well. I will issue a pull request on github project.

Comment: Nice! I already placed a bug report: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11805